# auto join/include a view in ef core through navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In an asp.net core app with ef core and identity, i have multiple different user types, each having their own entity and pointing to the identity user model. In this example these are `Panelist` and `SystemUser`.

Quite often you want the contact data for either the `SystemUser` or the `Panelist`, but joining on `AppUser` (i.e. `Panelist.Include(p => p.AppUser)`) is something i'd like to avoid, since this also joins a lot of unwanted columns, especially various security related hashes. Things i'd like not to expose. Everytime you would return such a user from a controller route you would need to ensure that either AutoMapper was applied or you manually selected the necessary properties.

```cs
class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    // inherited from IdentityUser: Email, 
    // PhoneNumber
}

class SystemUser
{
    public AppUser AppUser {get;set;}
    public string AppUserId {get;set;}
    // more properties 
}

class Panelist
{
    public AppUser AppUser {get;set;}
    public string AppUserId {get;set;}
    // more properties 
}
```

As a way out, i created a view:

```sql
-- as part of a migration in ef core
drop view if exists dbo.ContactDataView

create view dbo.ContactDataView as
    select user.Id, user.FullName, user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.PhoneNumber, user.Email
    from dbo.AppUser
```

and the matching c# side

```cs
public class ContactData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// user id from app user
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

in `DbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)`

```cs
        builder.Entity<Models.Views.ContactData>()
            .ToView("ContactDataView")
            .HasKey(contactData => contactData.Id);
```

The view works fine and as expected, but now i'd like to include it in one query to either of the user types through a navigation property. I am aware you could just manually join the contact data view in, but the goal (if that is possible within ef core) is to just write `dataContext.SystemUusers.Include(su => su.ContactData)`. In addition, ef core recently also supports auto includes, which would make this even more elegant.

Just adding a navigation property (which is only meant for tables, not views as far as i understand things) fails, since this will either generate an additional foreign key or complain about using `AppUserId` twice.

I am aware that AutoMapper might be a solution, but it's not an option for design reasons as this would introduce mapping logic right into your domain models. This project uses AutoMapper already though, but at a much later stage.

So long story short.

- was the view the right idea to begin with?
- is this possible in a somewhat clean way (i.e. auto joining it), if at all
- or, bite the bullet and query the view separately?

Other possible solutions all have various drawbacks. You could add computed columns for all contact data, that is very much overkill squared imho. You could duplicate the data in both user types, also not ideal. Creating two different views which does the join is also not an option, since i need these entities writable. Finally you could inherit from AppUser, but that would just shift the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would use `ProjectTo` and no, there is no mapping logic in your domain models. Unless you put it there, of course.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu
I know this solves the issue. But, long story short, i try to make it very 'domain driven design'ish' if that makes sense. Even though it's a pain sometimes. So having repositories which return something which is not an aggregate root feels wrong. Although you could of course map to itself. But that new result object would not be tracked by ef core anymore, right?

Comment: You don't need a repository to write a query. All you need is `ProjectTo`. Read models are very different from write models. And it's questionable how useful are repositories with EF. Do some research about it.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu
I know the EF context is almost (opinions vary) a Repository/UnitOfWork, i'm still using them, among other reasons because it is far easier to mock them for unit tests. ``ProjectTo`` is simply not applicable in this case. The contract, at least in imho, for a repo is to return a tracked instance, once you auto-map that is no longer possible afaik, As a use case, say you modifiy a user instance and send a mail about that. Needs to be writable, needs email in it. AutoMapper is great, but as i said, that only starts to come into play once controllers return view models.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Agreed, it is lets say more tedious. But you might also agree that i.e. using the ef data context directly in your controllers will very quickly lead to unmaintainable/untestable code.

Comment: You start with that and you refactor your way to higher level patterns when it becomes a problem, not before.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu
I'm already at that point :) The snippets above are part of a commercial web app which is already running in production. I want unit tests to verify certain methods enforce certain invariants and to catch regressions. Testing against DbContext is tricky, unless you're willing to test against an actual test database, which brings other problems. Hence the easily "moq"able repository interfaces. nonetheless, your feedback is appreciated ;)

Comment: I'd say you've made the bad trade off. You do need some kind of tests with DbContext and some without it and that can be done without the high cost in complexity you commited to.